# Agrupar por fecha + Hora dinámico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
name  fecha               valor
b1    12/07/2017 19:45     200
b1    12/07/2017 19:50     220
b1    12/07/2017 19:55     221
...
b1    13/07/2017 00:59     425
```

Es una tabla donde se guardan registros cada 5 minutos para cada name (b1, b2, b3... etc.) Necesito que los registros se agrupen por rango de horas es decir, 08:30 (del día presente) -> 01:00(del próximo día) y me genere un resultado así:

```
b1                       12/07/2017             1066
```

> Ejemplo: El día 12 me contempla desde 12/07/2017 08:30 am -> 13/07/2017 01:00 am

Teniendo presente que las fechas son dinámicas.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: A que te refieres con fechas dinamicas?

Comment: Me refiero a dinamico a que solo cambia la fecha la hora se mantiene

Comment: Daniel, con respecto al rango de fechas que quieres listar, cuantos días como máximo vas a querer ver?

Answer (score 0):

Simule el código en una tabla temporal solo haz los cambios que necesites

Tabla temporal

```
create table #tabla (
Name varchar(50),
Fecha datetime,
Valor int)
```

Registros

```
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 10:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 11:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 12:45', 180
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 13:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 14:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 15:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 16:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 17:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 18:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 19:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 20:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 21:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-01 23:45', 100
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 00:45', 100
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 01:45', 450
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 02:45', 450
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 05:45', 300
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 13:45', 200
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 10:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 11:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 12:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 13:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 14:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 15:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 16:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 17:45', 180
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 18:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 19:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 20:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 21:45', 500
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-02 23:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-03 00:45', 352
INSERT INTO #Tabla SELECT 'A', '2017-08-03 01:45', 352
```

Select

```
select Fecha2 = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) = 0 THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1, Fecha), 'yyyy-MM-dd') ELSE FORMAT(Fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd') END, SUM(Valor) from #Tabla GROUP BY CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) = 0 THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1, Fecha), 'yyyy-MM-dd') ELSE FORMAT(Fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd') END
```

eliminar tabla

```
drop table #Tabla
```

Espero te funcione

Comment: No me funca , la idea siguiendo la tabla con los registro que creaste, necesito que figure asi : A -> 2017-08-01 -> (SUMA DESDE  2017-08-01 10:45 -> 2017-08-02 00:45) YA QUE ESE PARA MI SERIA UN REGISTRO DE LOS HORARIOS 08:30 -> 01:00(DIA PROXIMO)  Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo :)

Comment: haz este select y veras como la columna fecha en el renglon 14 dice 00:45 y en la fecha calculada sigue diciendo 2017-08-01 `select Fecha, Fecha2 = CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) = 0 THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, -1, Fecha), 'yyyy-MM-dd') ELSE FORMAT(Fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd') END, Valor from #Tabla`

Comment: si lo que sucede que en el renglon 14 dice 00:45 la columna fecha, pero la columna fecha2 me dice : 2017-02-07 es raro como que hay un problema con la conversion de las fechas                                          

2017-01-08 23:45:00.000 2017-01-08 100
2017-02-08 00:45:00.000 2017-02-07 100
2017-02-08 01:45:00.000 2017-02-08 450

Comment: Es por que le quito un dia en caso de que la hora sea antes de la 1 am como esta en tu pregunta eso para poder agrupar por horas

Answer (score 0):

Al guardar cada registro guárdalos como” timestamp”
Para esto en tu tabla de MYSQL el campo que tienes con el nombre fecha hazlo tipo timestamp.

```
ALTER TABLE `nombre_de_tu_tabla` CHANGE `fecha` `fecha` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Le puedes poner default la fecha actual del momento cuando se guarda o NULL. Solo asegúrate de configurar la hora del servidor o enviarlo desde tu código en el formato adecuado para timestamp.
Después de eso basta con hacer la consulta por fecha:

```
SELECT * FROM `nombre_de_tu_tabla` ORDER BY `nombre_de_tu_tabla`.`fecha` ASC
```

Comment: La base de datos es SQL server